# Проблема с запуском приложения на Android 8.1.0 из-за root'a в параметре TestKeys

Tags: android, root

В наличии китайский POS-терминал на Android 8.1.0 на него установлено приложение (Cashalot) программное РРО, после очередного обновления приложение перестало запускаться, в тех. поддержке приложения сказали что проблема связана с рут-доступом и нужно проверить с помощью RootBeer Sample и в параметре TestKeys действительно оказались root-права. Можно как-то переписать тестовые ключи или обмануть само приложение? Не до конца понимаю вообще что к чему, кроме того что не стоит покупать сомнительные китайские девайсы).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При проверке терминала на root-права с помощью RootBeer Sample отображается root в параметре TestKeys из-за этого не могу запустить необходимое мне приложение Cashalot